# Finding out the increasing subsequence in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

Suppose I have table of x and y values where y is ordered DESC, for example

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  94 | 985
  73 | 940
 469 | 865
 115 | 864
 366 | 862
 525 | 842
 448 | 837
 318 | 832
 507 | 826
 244 | 758
 217 | 741
 207 | 732
  54 | 688
 426 | 605
 108 | 604
 610 | 587
 142 | 581
 765 | 579
 102 | 572
 512 | 552
 836 | 540
```

now I want to find increasing subsequence of x starting from the first value 
i.e.the I wish to obtain the following output where x is following an increasing order.

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  94 | 985
 469 | 865
 525 | 842
 610 | 587
 765 | 579
 836 | 540
```

Is this possible through sql query or do I need to use plpgsql function and loop while updating the maximum?

Comment: remove the bonus question and post it as a new one.

Comment: This problem has no solution.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Okay I will make some editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the running max with `max` window function. Essentially your output asks for that.

```
select distinct max(val) over(order by id) --replace id with your ordering column
from t
```

Edit: After OP's edit of the question

```
select x,y 
from (select distinct y,x,max(x) over(order by y desc) running_x_max
      from t
     ) t
where running_x_max=x
order by y desc
```

Comment: I didn't max function could perform such a magic, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the original question using `lead()`, assuming you have a column specifying the ordering:

```
select x.*
from (select t.*, sum( (next_x < x)::int) over (order by orderingcol) as grp
      from (select t.*, lead(x) over (order by orderingcol) as next_x
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp = 0;
```

EDIT:

The above will leave out the last element.  I know I should have written with `lag()`, and then I rewrote it with `lead()`.  So, a better version is:

```
select x.*
from (select t.*, sum( case when x < prev_x then 1 else 0 end ) over (order by orderingcol) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(x) over (order by orderingcol) as prev_x
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is one small drawback however, the numbers don't necessarily just skip by one row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for the given order you have column called id, you can use window function `max` with window specification:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        case when x >= max(x) over (
                    order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                    ) then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from t
    ) t
where flag = 1;-- or 0 if you want to get the remaining ones.
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/TDNTX98521)

#### [Demo for "bonus" one](http://rextester.com/SMKX65589)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand what are unbounded preceding and current row.

Comment: @Peter it's a mechanism to define the window start and end point for a window function such as max, sum, count etc.