# Finding increasing subsequence n times in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

Followed by my previous question on finding the increasing subsequence in a data set.

[Finding out the increasing subsequence in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054117/finding-out-the-increasing-subsequence-in-sql)

To obtain the result

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  94 | 985
 469 | 865
 525 | 842
 610 | 587
 765 | 579
```

from

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  94 | 985
  73 | 940
 469 | 865
 115 | 864
 366 | 862
 525 | 842
 448 | 837
 318 | 832
 507 | 826
 244 | 758
 217 | 741
 207 | 732
  54 | 688
 426 | 605
 108 | 604
 610 | 587
 142 | 581
 765 | 579
 102 | 572
```

I can apply the query

```
select x, y
from (select max(x) over (order by y desc) as x_max, x, max(y) over (order by x desc) as y_max, y
    from table
    order by y desc, x desc) t
where t.x = t.x_max and t.y = t.y_max
order by y desc, x
```

Now my question is, how can I perform this operation n times, i.e. finding the 2nd, 3rd, ..., nth increasing subsequence of x.
I know the general idea is to take the result of the first operation from the original table and perform the the query on the remaining points.

So in my example, after the first operation, we have the remaining points,

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  73 | 940
 115 | 864
 366 | 862
 448 | 837
 318 | 832
 507 | 826
 244 | 758
 217 | 741
 207 | 732
  54 | 688
 426 | 605
 108 | 604
 142 | 581
 102 | 572
```

and apply the query again, we get

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  73 | 940
 115 | 864
 366 | 862
 448 | 837
 507 | 826
```

And perform the operation on

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
 318 | 832
 244 | 758
 217 | 741
 207 | 732
  54 | 688
 426 | 605
 108 | 604
 142 | 581
 102 | 572
```

so on and so forth. I would also like to union all the points from these query searches and order them by y desc, i.e.

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  73 | 940
  94 | 985
 115 | 864
 366 | 862
 448 | 837
 469 | 865
 507 | 826
 525 | 842
 610 | 587
 765 | 579
```

Comment: Recursive Query Evaluation?
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial & far from optimal, but you can indeed do this with recursive CTEs:

```
with recursive r as(
  (select   x, y, (running_x_max <> x)::int grp, 0 iteration
   from     (select *, max(x) over (order by y desc) running_x_max
             from   xy) t
   order by 3, 2 desc)
  union all
  (select   x, y, grp + (running_x_max <> x)::int, iteration + 1
   from     (select *, max(x) over (order by y desc) running_x_max
             from   r
             where  grp > iteration) t
   order by 3, 2 desc)
)
select   x, y, grp
from     r
where    grp = iteration
order by 3, 2 desc, 1
```

http://rextester.com/JDYJ58330